# Does Stripe Google Pay integration can be tested with Google's test card suite?

Tags: stripe-payments, google-pay

I am trying to setup my Google account correctly so that this Stripe [Payment Element demo](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-element) would show Google Pay option.

I have added my Google account to [test card suite group](https://groups.google.com/g/googlepay-test-mode-stub-data) as per [Google's instruction](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/resources/test-card-suite). I can successfully use test suite cards in [Google's Pay button demo](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/demos).

However, I still cannot see Google Pay neither in Payment Element demo, nor in the old [Payment Request Element demo](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button).

I'm using latest Chrome.

**Can I use Google's test card suite to test Stripe Google Pay integration?**

**Or is my only option to use real cards?**

Comment: You should be able to use the test card suite to test Google Pay with Stripe. As an example, it work nicely here for me (last example): https://stripe.dev/elements-examples/

Comment: I was also able to use the test card suite with that example.

Comment: @singularity-fx - in addition to that: Stripe sometimes will show you their own "Link" payment method instead of Google Pay. So make sure that you browse the examples when logged in to your Google account and make sure to have a card on https://payments.google.com/gp/w/u/0/home/paymentmethods - after that you should be able to see to Google Pay button and you can use the test card suite to complete a transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you must connect a real, valid card to your wallet.

If your Stripe implementation is initialized with your test keys, then no payment will go through.

Related documentation:
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button#html-js-testing
The documentation that explains this best is actually related to Apple Pay, even though it's the same principle for both wallets:
https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay?platform=ios#testing-apple-pay